# How to handle inconsistent radio button options?

Tags: gui-design, radio-buttons

I'm trying to understand if an approach we're taking with the following is bad UI or not.

We're a staffing application for finance and accounting professionals. In this experience, we ask a client (someone looking to hire said professional) during registration to tell us a role they're interested in hiring.

We present the client with four radio buttons. The first three each expose four unique cards that show representative titles in a given area (first image.

The fourth radio button exposes an input field that allows the client to enter their own title.

Should we present the 4th option differently? It seems odd that with three of the radio buttons we show cards and show an input field with the fourth.

It's worth noting that my company's strength is in staffing the roles covered in the first three radio buttons, so we want to visually emphasize those.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to combine a radio button with a text field. In my opinion, to make it more understandable the alternative option to choose should be `Other`. From there, transform the label into a text field with clarification if necessary.

[image]

This solution is taken from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65536269/5765312)

Comment: Nice!

In screen 1 above, if a user were to click the "Other" radio button, would you hide the four cards?

Comment: I don't see it necessary, that depends on design choices

Answer (score 0):

You could also partially maintain the same pattern.
The user selects "Custom Role" radio button and you show a card with a silhouette and ask the user to enter the role there.